# Using R function put_object from package aws.s3 to load files into a specific S3 bucket

Tags: r, aws.s3

I can successfully put an object (pdf file) into my S3 bucket base folder using the put_object function from aws.s3. However, it doesn't work when I specify a folder in the function. I don't get any error messages and the output in R looks like it has worked:

```
[1] TRUE
```

This is my code:

```
put_object(file = "myfile.pdf", object = "myfile2.pdf", bucket = "my_bucket", folder = 'folder/subfolder1/subfolder2' )
```

I've read the package documentation and the post [here](https://www.stackoverflow.com/) .

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create a "folder" in S3 you have to use the other function from the package:

```
put_folder(folder, bucket, ...)
```

If you want to put a file inside that "folder" you have to specify the destination key:

```
put_object(file = "myfile.pdf", object = "folder/subfolder1/subfolder2/myfile2.pdf", bucket = "my_bucket")
```

As described [here](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/aws.s3/versions/0.3.21/topics/put_object).

PS: There are only objects is S3.

Comment: Thanks mate, That worked. I just got confused with argument 'folder' in the function.